# Corvertir una cadena de texto a formato de fecha

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos tengo la siguiente cadena `09/20/2018 12:21 PM` la cual quiero convertir a formato de fecha para insertarlo en una columna de una base de datos de MySQL que tiene de `datetime` he intentado con la función `strtotime`pero el resultado que obtengo es del un entero algo como `int(201021)` no se convertirlo para insertarlo.

Comment: ¿Y porque no guardas esa cadena asi 09/20/2018 12:21 PM?

Comment: @Oswuell porque ocupo forzosamente que este en formato de fecha.

Comment: ¿qué tipo de dato tiene el campo en la tabla de la base de datos?

Comment: @track3r `datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para convertir ese formato a formato SQL, prueba esto.

```
<?php
function conv_fecha($string) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i A', $string);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

echo conv_fecha('09/20/2018 12:21 PM');
echo conv_fecha('10/02/2018 01:21 AM');
```

Resultado

```
2018-09-20 12:21:00
2018-10-02 01:21:00
```

[ Edit ]
Si el formato de hora es sin 0 a la izquierda (1:25 PM), utiliza "g" minuscula en vez de "h", siguiendo lo que dice la documentacion de PHP http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Comment: ¡Excelente! Funciono muy bien.

Comment: @LuisMiguel hice una modificacion en la funcion que por error puse H mayuscula. Es h minuscula o bien g, dependiendo de tu formato de hora.